# Inverse Function Theorem (Domain, one-to-one, application)

Tags: calculus, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

$f(x) = e^x + \ln(x)$

Q1) Find the Domain

Q2) Show that $f$ is one-to-one

Q3) Find $(f^{-1})(e)$

Q4) Find the derivative of the inverse function at $e$.

---

I am pretty much at a loss for how to apply the IFT.

Q1)

```
I know the domain of $f^{-1}$ = range of $f$ 

I know that the range of $f^{-1}$ = domain of $f$
```

Q2)

```
I know that I need to check the signs of the derivative and if it is 
always positive then it must be one-to-one but why is that the case?
```

Q3 & Q4)

```
I think this is where the theorem is supposed to be applied just not 
sure how.
```

If someone could walk me through how to solve these problems utilizing the IFT that would be appreciated very much. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $f^{-1}(e)$ is the same as $f(x)=e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q_1): Since $\ln$ is only defined for $x>0$, $f$ has the domain $(0, \infty)$.

Q_2): For $x>0$ we have $f'(x)=e^x+ \frac{1}{x} >0$. Conclusion ?

Q_3): $f(1)=e$, conclusion ?

Q_4): $(f^{-1})'(e)=\frac{1}{f'(1)}= ?$

Answer (score 0):

The first part is asking for the domain of $f(x)=e^x+\ln(x)$. Recall that $e^x$ is defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$, but $\ln(x)$ is only defined for $x>0$. The domain of the function is the intersection of the domains of $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$, which is $x>0$ or $\Bbb R^+$.

As for the second part, as you have correctly pointed out, you need to differentiate $f$ and see the sign of the derivative. If the derivative of a differentiable function is always positive or always negative, the function is injective.

To see why, recall that Rolle's Theorem tells us for a function $h(x)$ continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b), h(a)=h(b)\implies\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Take the contrapositive of this: $\forall c\in(a,b),f'(c)\ne0\implies h(a)\ne h(b)$. If the derivative is either always positive or always negative in $(a,b)$, it is never zero and $h(a)\ne h(b)$. You can extend this to any arbitray $a,b$ in the domain.

For the third part, you can easily inspect $f(1)=e$.

For the last part, recall that $f(f^{-1}(x))=x\implies f'(f^{-1}(x))\cdot (f^{-1})'(x)=1$. Putting $x=e$, we get,

$$f'(1)\cdot(f^{-1})'(e)=1$$

Can you solve it further?